# How Can I change the post_max_size in php.ini file?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change the post_max_size from 3M to 100M, i also changed the upload_max_filesize but it's not working, cause when i print echo ini_get('post_max_size'); i always get 3M.

What else Do i have to change in php.ini in order to increment post_size?

This is for a html form which has an input type file, It works fine with files with sizes less than 3m

NOTE: I am using WAMP SERVER

Comment: Did you try restart your server?

Comment: Yes buddy, many times

Comment: Is this a shared server? In which case you're not allowed to change ini settings.

Comment: My Server is wamp server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest pitfalls for changing PHP.ini configurations is, that you use the wrong file. So create a php file with following content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

There you will get a table with the most important infos about your installation. Have a look at the row  of the php.ini file, which will look maybe like this:

```
Loaded Configuration File:  C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Make your changes to this file (from your phpinfo()). After every change, you have to restart your Apache.

Comment: sh..t son, you are great, this is my php.ini C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini, i was using this address C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini

Comment: I spent like 6 moderfakas hours trying to solve this

Comment: Yes, this is an error I have done myself so many times as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
```

More informations: http://php.net/manual/de/function.ini-set.php
Or as Jozef Dúc recommended: try apache server restart.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini go to following line

```
post_max_size = 3M
```

Suppose change 3M to 10M if you want to change post size to 10mb.

Please don't forget to restart PHP service to apply changes.

Comment: @user4216713 Which server you are using like WAMP, XAMP?

Comment: WAMP buddy, I using WAMP SERVEr

Comment: @user4216713 go to `C:\wamp\bin\php\your-php-version-here\php.ini` and change in this file and restart. If have tested this on my localhost too and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After saving changes, you must restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but at a certain time I couldn't upload certain dimension files.
I changed any config and get crazy.

Then had an idea. I got under thie /etc/php folder:

```
cd /etc/php
```

And searched for the magic words "post_max_size"

```
grep -rnw . -e "post_max_size"
```

And found that a @arg@sh@fu@ file stored this line. The result is this one

```
./7.4/apache2/php.ini:694:post_max_size = 100M
./7.4/cli/php.ini:694:post_max_size = 8M
```

So the cli/php.ini I never never used was getting me crazy.
I had nooooooo idea why my server was working fine uploading 100M files and from a day to an other switched to the cli file...
But the solution is this one. Search into files your key word.

I spend 20 hours on this!!! FOr quite nothing. :(